# Assign dynamic IPv6 address to azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I'm attempting to setup my Azure virtual network to be able to automatically assign ipv4 and ipv6 addresses to VM's I create.

I've configured my virtual network and subnet to include both IPv4 and IPv6 address ranges.

I'm not sure what do to do after this though. When I create a VM and attach it to my subnet, it still only assigns a dynamic IPv4 address.

I've found this resource... https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/public-ip?view=azure-cli-latest

With this I've been able to create a public dynamic IPv6 address in my selected resource group. However I only have the option to associate this with a load balancer, not directly with a VM.

Does this mean that IPv6 addresses only work with load balancers?

Comment: Windows or Linux VMs?

Comment: @SamCogan I'm mostly trying to get it to work for windows, but I've tried Linux as well.

Comment: Ok, Linus requires tour have the DHCPv6 client installed but Windows shouldn’t need changes

Comment: I ended up just creating a basic load balancer, and assigning ipv6 this way. It's probably a better solution overall, and basic load balancers don't cost anything anyway.

Comment: @user1751825 Didn't you have to assign another public IPv4 address to the load balancer?